# Enter messages that contain carriage returns

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a web application in vb.net that has a textbox which is set as multiline enabled. This text box value is bind in a label which is under a div.

I want to add messages that contains carriage returns. How can i achieve this?

```
<tr>
    <td class="style4" height="100px" align="right">
        Message:
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" runat="server" MaxLength="500" CssClass="formInputTextDate" Height="97px" Width="275px" TextMode="MultiLine" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have added this in item field in the grid:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Message">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("fMessage").ToString().Replace(<linebreak>,"<br />") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This text box message save in to database and that field is bind with a label.

Comment: Can you share some code? Your question doesn't give much information to go on. Is it that you don't know how to enter a carriage return into the textbox when testing in the browser? Or do you want to add some text to the textbox from your code, and that text has a carriage return?

Comment: Yes Dan, that text has a carriage return.

Comment: When I click enter in the textbox it should be come with new line in label

Comment: Do you mean that you have text in the textbox, and you want that same text to appear in the label, with newlines intact?

Comment: Yes Dan, The same i want :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `<br/>` instead but this should give you an idea of how to pre-process the text

```
    Dim message = "Hello" + Environment.NewLine + "World"

    Dim parts = message.Split(Environment.NewLine)
    Dim builder = New StringBuilder
    For Each part As String In parts
        builder.AppendFormat("<p>{0}</p>", part)
    Next
```

Comment: But how could i use environment.new line in textbox ?

Comment: Do you mean that you want your text box to allow the input of carriage returns or is your problem with entries that already have carriage returns?

Comment: Yes, text box to allow the input of carriage returns

Comment: @Mark This is a situation where Environment.NewLine is the wrong thing to use: the line separator in an HTML <TEXTAREA> is defined to be CRLF. If you were to use Environment.NewLine in Mono, it is likely to be LF only.

Comment: <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Message">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("fMessage").ToString().Replace(<linebreak>,"<br />") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>